Spark stream to stream join failing with error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error reading delta file
I am reading two streams as dataframe from Kafka, joining them and trying to process the joined DF as below
private def readStream(spark: SparkSession, topicName: String, schema: StructType): DataFrame = {
  spark
    .readStream
    .format(source = "kafka")
    .option(Constants.KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS, Constants.KAFKA_BROKERS)
    .option("subscribe", topicName)
    .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
    .option("kafkaConsumer.pollTimeoutMs", 1200)
    .option("fetchOffset.numRetries", 20)
    .option("fetchOffset.retryIntervalMs", 250)
    .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 200)
    .option("failOnDataLoss", value = false)
    .load()
    .selectExpr(exprs = "CAST(value AS STRING) data")
    .select(from_json(col("data"), schema) as "data")
    .selectExpr("data.*")
}


override def run(spark: SparkSession, config: Config, params: Map[String, String]): Unit = {
  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  val (topic1, topic2)  = ("topic1", "topic2")
  val schema1 = StructType(Seq( StructField("id", LongType), /* other columns */))
  val schema2 = StructType(Seq( StructField("wallet_transaction_id", LongType), /* other columns */))

  val df1 = readStream(spark, topic1, schema1)
    .withWatermark(Constants.UPDATED_AT, "10 seconds")

  val df2 = readStream(spark, topic2, schema2)
    .withWatermark(Constants.UPDATED_AT, "10 seconds")

  val df = df1.alias("df1").join(df2.alias("df2"), expr(
    """
      |df1.id = df2.wallet_transaction_id
      |and df2.updated_at between df1.updated_at and df1.updated_at + interval 2 seconds
      |""".stripMargin))

    df
      .writeStream
      .option("checkpointLocation", "s3://bucket-name/location/of/checkpoint")
      .format("console")
//        .foreachBatch(processBatch _)
      .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(0))
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()
}

private def processBatch(df: DataFrame, batchId: Long): Unit = {
  df.show(false)
  println(s"""batch ID y: $batchId current date: ${LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"))}""")
}

When I run with writeStream.format("console") it runs perfectly. But with foreachBatch, after 2-3 batch runs it gives delta file not found error.
error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error reading delta file
I have checked the S3 location, I case of format("console") it writes all the delta files. But in other case, it writes delta files for few runs, but after that the delta file is missing.
